# Python syntax error in the if_else condition - why is this happening?

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax

I have an error in Python for the `parse_extensions` function.
The error is on the last "else"(the last if and else condition) with the description "Invalid Syntax"
How can I fix it and why is this a syntax error?

```
def parse_extension(payload, type_name):
        entries = []
        pretty_entries = []
        pointer = 0
        format_list_length = 2
        if type_name == 'elliptic_curves':
            format_entry = 2
        if type_name == 'ec_point_formats':
            format_entry = 1
        if type_name == 'heartbeat':
            format_entry = 1
        if type_name == 'compression_methods':
            format_entry = 1
        if type_name == 'cipher_suites':
            format_entry = 2
        else:
            if len(payload) > 1:  # contents are a list
                list_length, payload = unpacker(payload, format_list_length)    
        if type_name == 'padding':
            return payload, hexlify(payload)
        if type_name == 'signature_algorithms':
            format_entry = 2
        if type_name == 'status_request' or type_name == 'status_request_v2':
            _type, payload = unpacker(payload, 1)
            format_entry = 2
        if list_length:
             payload = payload[:list_length] 
        while (len(payload) > 0):
            if type_name == 'server_name':
                type_server, payload = unpacker(payload, 1)
                
            entry, pointer1 = parse(payload, format_entry)
            pointer += pointer1
            payload = payload[pointer:]
            entries.append(entry)
            
            if type_name in set('elliptic_curves','ec_point_formats','heartbeat',
                                  'compression_methods','cipher_suites'):
                pretty_entries.append(tls_dictionary(type_name, entry)
                
            *else:*
                pretty_entries.append(entry) 
        return entries, pretty_entries
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a bracket here:

```py
pretty_entries.append(tls_dictionary(type_name, entry)
```

To

```py
pretty_entries.append(tls_dictionary(type_name, entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra bracket to `pretty_entries.append(tls_dictionary(type_name, entry)`, making it `pretty_entries.append(tls_dictionary(type_name, entry))`.